# Record and upload audio in jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to make a audio recorder in which user can record audio and upload.But the audio is not getting upload.Any ideas how i can fix this.Thanks in advance...

Here is error

> Warning  file_get_contents(blob:http://localhost/21ab2fc2-103b-44a8-9fe1-2152ca61d9ea.wav): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **C:\xampp\htdocs\drag-drop-image-uploader1\audio\upload.php** on line **34**

Here is my code...

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Audio Recorder</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://stephino.github.io/dist/favicon.png" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">L

        <style type="text/css">
        body {
            position: absolute;
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -webkit-flex;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-box-pack: center;
            -webkit-justify-content: center;
            -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
            -webkit-box-align: center;
            -webkit-align-items: center;
            -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .holder {
            background-color: #4c474c;
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(#4c474c), to(#141414));
            background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #4c474c 0%, #141414 100%);
            background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #4c474c 0%, #141414 100%);
            border-radius: 50px;
        }
        [data-role="controls"] > button {
            margin: 50px auto;
            outline: none;
            display: block;
            border: none;
            background-color: #D9AFD9;
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(#D9AFD9), to(#97D9E1));
            background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #D9AFD9 0%, #97D9E1 100%);
            background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #D9AFD9 0%, #97D9E1 100%);
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            text-indent: -1000em;
            cursor: pointer;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3) inset, 
            0px 0px 0px 30px #fff, 0px 0px 0px 35px #333;
            box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3) inset, 
            0px 0px 0px 30px #fff, 0px 0px 0px 35px #333;
        }
        [data-role="controls"] > button:hover {
            background-color: #ee7bee;
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(#ee7bee), to(#6fe1f5));
            background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #ee7bee 0%, #6fe1f5 100%);
            background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #ee7bee 0%, #6fe1f5 100%);
        }
        [data-role="controls"] > button[data-recording="true"] {
            background-color: #ff2038;
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(#ff2038), to(#b30003));
            background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #ff2038 0%, #b30003 100%);
            background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #ff2038 0%, #b30003 100%);
        }
        [data-role="recordings"] > .row {
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            padding: 20px;
        }
        [data-role="recordings"] > .row > audio {
            outline: none;
        }
        [data-role="recordings"] > .row > a {
            display: inline-block;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 20px;
            line-height: 50px;
            vertical-align: middle;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            border-radius: 20px;
            color: #fff;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-decoration: underline;
            background-color: #0093E9;
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(#0093E9), to(#80D0C7));
            background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #0093E9 0%, #80D0C7 100%);
            background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #0093E9 0%, #80D0C7 100%);
            float: right;
            margin-left: 20px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        [data-role="recordings"] > .row > a:hover {
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        [data-role="recordings"] > .row > a:active {
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0093E9), to(#80D0C7));
            background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0093E9 0%, #80D0C7 100%);
            background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #0093E9 0%, #80D0C7 100%);
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stephino.github.io/dist/recorder.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            var $ = jQuery;
            var myRecorder = {
                objects: {
                    context: null,
                    stream: null,
                    recorder: null
                },
                init: function () {
                    if (null === myRecorder.objects.context) {
                        myRecorder.objects.context = new (
                            window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext
                            );
                    }
                },
                start: function () {
                    var options = {audio: true, video: false};
                    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(options).then(function (stream) {
                        myRecorder.objects.stream = stream;
                        myRecorder.objects.recorder = new Recorder(
                            myRecorder.objects.context.createMediaStreamSource(stream),
                            {numChannels: 1}
                            );
                        myRecorder.objects.recorder.record();
                    }).catch(function (err) {});
                },
                stop: function (listObject) {
                    if (null !== myRecorder.objects.stream) {
                        myRecorder.objects.stream.getAudioTracks()[0].stop();
                    }
                    if (null !== myRecorder.objects.recorder) {
                        myRecorder.objects.recorder.stop();

                            // Validate object
                            if (null !== listObject
                                && 'object' === typeof listObject
                                && listObject.length > 0) {
                                // Export the WAV file
                            myRecorder.objects.recorder.exportWAV(function (blob) {
                                var url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL)
                                .createObjectURL(blob);
                                    // Prepare the playback
                                    var audioObject = $('<audio controls></audio>')
                                    .attr('src', url);
                                    var link = url+'.wav';
                                    $('#audio').attr('value',link);
                                    var blob = new Blob([link], {type: 'audio/wav'});
                                    var reader = new FileReader();
                                    reader.onload = function () {
                                      var b64 = reader.result.replace(/^data:.+;base64,/, '');
                                      console.log(b64);

                                  };
                                 
                                  alert(link)
                                  reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
                                  // alert(link)
                                  var form_data = new FormData();
                                  form_data.append('audio', link) ;
                                console.log(form_data);
                                  $.ajax({
                                    url: "upload.php", 
                                    cache: false,
                                    contentType: false,
                                    processData: false,
                                    data: form_data, 
                                    type: 'post',
                                    success: function(data) {
                                      console.log(data);
                                  }
                              });
                                    // Prepare the download link
                                    var downloadObject = $('<a>&#9660;</a>')
                                    .attr('href', url)
                                    .attr('download', new Date().toUTCString() + '.wav');

                                    // Wrap everything in a row
                                    var holderObject = $('<div class="row"></div>')
                                    .append(audioObject)
                                    .append(downloadObject);

                                    // Append to the list
                                    listObject.append(holderObject);
                                });
                        }
                    }
                }

            };

                // Prepare the recordings list
                var listObject = $('[data-role="recordings"]');

                // Prepare the record button
                $('[data-role="controls"] > button').click(function () {
                    // Initialize the recorder
                    myRecorder.init();

                    // Get the button state 
                    var buttonState = !!$(this).attr('data-recording');

                    // Toggle
                    if (!buttonState) {
                        $(this).attr('data-recording', 'true');
                        myRecorder.start();
                    } else {
                        $(this).attr('data-recording', '');
                        myRecorder.stop(listObject);
                    }
                });
                $('#clicked').click(function(){
                                  
                                  
                })
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="holder">
            <div data-role="controls">
                <button>Record</button>
            </div>
            <div data-role="recordings"></div>
        </div>
            <input type="file" name="audio" id="audio" class="d-none">
        <button id="clicked">post</button>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    $data = $_POST['audio'];
$audio = file_get_contents($data);
$audio1 = file_put_contents(".wav",$audio);
echo $audio;
echo $data;
print_r($_FILES);
print_r($_POST); 
?>
    ?>
```

Comment: `blob:http://localhost/21ab2fc2-103b-44a8-9fe1-2152ca61d9ea.wav` is not a valid filename, thats one of your problems

Comment: Then what should i do.....